# Problem with option border of class standalone

Tags: standalone

I tested a MWE given in question [Standalone producing cropped / truncated formulae](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53220/standalone-producing-cropped-truncated-formulae). Following the documentation (page 9) I used the class option `border={left right bottom top}` with `left=right=top=0pt` and `bottom=20pt` (20pt only to show the effect here).

With the version 2012/09/15 v1.1b of `standalone` and the following MWE I get no 20 pt margin at the bottom of my picture.  What is the problem?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
% border=1pt
  border={0pt 0pt 20pt 0pt} %left right bottom top
]{standalone}% http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone
\begin{document}
$2^5 = x_5 \times y^8$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It seems that the given order for option `border`:

> left right bottom top

is wrong.

Exchange the position of `20pt` in line 3 of the given MWE in the question and you can see that the right order is:

> left bottom right top

Is this an error in the code or in the documentation? I will ask the autor.

The complete MWE is:

```
\documentclass[%
% border=1pt
  border={0pt 20pt 0pt 0pt} % left bottom right top
]{standalone}% http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone
\begin{document}
$2^5 = x_5 \times y^8$
\end{document}
```

to receive a picture with a bottom margin of 20pt (to have the heading not so close to the picture).

Comment: it appears to me that the error is in the documentation.  logically, `left right bottom top` just proceeds left-right-down-up, so it doesn't really cover all four sides, whereas `left bottom right top` "draws" a rectangle counterclockwise around the boundary.  please do notify the author.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: well, how about fixing it upstream then? :) it's still wrong in your bitbucket (>4 years later).

Comment: @stefanct: Sorry, I'm rather busy and didn't coded any LaTeX for a while. But I corrected it now: https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/commits/ef6d3e2eeb053b8a0c654f90315c1329052b7276

Comment: When I posted my duplicate question, I was not aware of your question. Interestingly, I didn't even receive any notification that my question is a duplicate. Anyway, this is just to say sorry that I missed your question.