# How can i get a HUGE LaTeX picture?

Tags: fontsize

I can't find a way to get a huuuge LaTeX "picture"

This is my best attempt, http://www.forkosh.com/mimetextutorial.html

Fill in:

```
 \Huge s=\frac{v^2+v_o}{2a}
```

so, how is the best way to get a huge one?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Well, I don't really understand your question. The site you link seems to actually use some LaTeX "clone" and not a real LaTeX. What exactly is your intention?

Comment: Are you interested in enlarging a math equation and then exporting it as a picture so that the entire thing is very big? You should define what you mean by "huuuge". Is a single equation filling an entire letter sized paper huge? What about size A0 then?

Comment: @Werner He is developing an app where he wants to display formulas, and using texify.com gives you an image as output (making it easy to put into an app). The size he wants is about enough to display it on a iPad Air and mini, aka very high resolution and size.

Comment: @tohecz He is developing an app where he wants to display formulas, and using texify.com gives you an image as output (making it easy to put into an app). The size he wants is about enough to display it on a iPad Air and mini, aka very high resolution and size.

Comment: Yes, i want to make a large math equation, exported as a picture. and i want A4 -ish size, of the whole equation.

Comment: Hi @OscarApeland... that's not at all what I read in the question. Perhaps the OP can clarify. Regardless, just displaying a *very large* equation is easy: `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{$\displaystyle s=\frac{v^2+v_o}{2a}$}` when you also `\usepackage{graphicx}`. You could also use `\usepackage[paper=A4,landscape]{geometry}`.

Comment: @OleB: So you're creating this image stand-alone, or online?

Comment: @Werner Nah its not but he's somewhat mentally challenged. I'm on facetime with him right now, so I know what he really wants.

Comment: im doing it online

Comment: he wants equations rendered to images using a tool like texify.com, just bigger. that guy who mentioned using size A0, how do you do that?

Comment: @OscarApeland: My suggestion using [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) and [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx), together with a `\resize{\linewidth}{!}{$\displaystyle ...$}` should work then...

Comment: Could you provide a full example on how you would display a very basic formula (like zero point equation) in a very huge size in the answers below? :D

Comment: @Werner We are really new to this, incase you didn't notice.

Comment: @OscarApeland: Will this be created dynamically (or on the fly), or do you just want to create the image once? If it's the latter, you can actually use an alternative full-scale editor (rather than [texify.com](http://www.texify.com)), like [ShareLaTeX](http://sharelatex.com). It's obvious that texify.com does not handle the inclusion of extra packages.

Comment: Only once, he plans to pre-render them, as its hard to render them on-device (javascript workarounds)

Comment: @OscarApeland: Then you need to use an editor/environment that can load packages (like [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)), similar to Przemysław Scherwentke's answer. Then you can copy-and-paste it in the editor, compile, render a PDF and then convert it using some other external tool. Specifically, I think the following might be a duplicate then: [Standalone producing cropped / truncated formulae](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53220/5764). Regardless, you would *need* a more comprehensive editor (online or offline).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand, you simply want to scale your equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}


$s=\frac{v^2+v_o}{2a}$


\scalebox{10}{$s=\frac{v^2+v_o}{2a}$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: Rather `v_0`, not `v_o`.

Comment: [That didn't work too well](http://www.texify.com/img/%5CLARGE%5C%21%5Cdocumentclass%7Barticle%7D%5Cusepackage%7Bgraphics%7D%5Cbegin%7Bdocument%7D%24s%3D%5Cfrac%7Bv%5E2%2Bv_o%7D%7B2a%7D%24%5Cscalebox%7B10%7D%7B%24s%3D%5Cfrac%7Bv%5E2%2Bv_o%7D%7B2a%7D%24%7D%5Cend%7Bdocument%7D.gif)