# How to color equations in TeXify

Tags: math-mode, color

I am using [texify.com](http://www.texify.com) to generate images of equations, so that I can put them in emails. I am trying to insert a colored equation, using the following code:

```
{\color{green} dy} = {\color{red} \frac{dy}{dx}} {\color{green}  dx}
```

However, the image produced is entirely green, including the equals sign and fraction bar. Am I coding this incorrectly, or does it just not work on the website?

(Of course, if there are better ways to put math equations into emails - I use gmail primarily - I am all ears!)

Comment: I think it is a problem with their website since the code itself does work. For getting a simple image of an equation you can use a tool like LaTeXiT on OSX. There is a alternative KLatex which says it is available on all platforms. I never used it though. However, a simple image of an equation can be achieved using \documentclass[preview]{standalone} and then email that equation sized pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TeXify](http://www.texify.com) parses the code differently than the [tutorial page](http://www.forkosh.com/mimetextutorial.html):

[image]

My suggestion is to use that page instead, or use the technique described in [Standalone producing cropped / truncated formulae](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53220/5764).

Answer (score 0):

> Of course, if there are better ways to put math equations into emails
>   - I use gmail primarily - I am all ears!

You can use [GmailTeX](http://alexeev.org/gmailtex.html). This plugin which adds (La)TeX capability to Gmail and Gmail Chat.

[image]