# How to set the baseline of a box?

Tags: boxes, baseline

I want to change the baseline of a box so that the depth of the box is equal to that of a letter with a descender in the current font.  So far I have only been successful in setting the baseline to the bottom of the box by wrapping the box in a `\vbox` and using `\vtop`, but this isn't exactly what I want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\aberrantbox{\vrule height8pt depth5pt width5pt}

\begin{document}
Line \aberrantbox \vtop{\vbox{\hbox{\aberrantbox}\kern 0pt}}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried various combinations of `\smash` and `\phantom` but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Do you want something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NBB7S.png)?

Comment: @Werner I want this alignment at the bottom but without changing the total height.

Comment: I've used `\newcommand\abox{\vrule height\ht\strutbox depth\dp\strutbox width5pt}
\newcommand\bbox{\setbox8=\hbox{q}\setbox9=\hbox{d}\vrule height\ht9 depth\dp8 width5pt}` with the left box set using `\abox` and the right with `\bbox`. I don't understand what you mean by "without changing the total height"...

Comment: depending on the font (and after looking at @Werner;s example), you could try `\vphantom{qb}`, `\vphantom{XQ}` and `\vphantom{()}` since different fonts have different designs with heights/depths of ascenders, descenders, and fences; those examples should give you an idea of what's an appropriate setting..

Comment: I mean that I want the height + depth of the box to remain unchanged. In your picture the box is clipped at the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raise the box by its depth minus the depth of a letter with a descender:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\aberrantbox}{\vrule height8pt depth5pt width5pt}

\begin{document}
Line \aberrantbox
\raisebox{\dimexpr\depth-\fontchardp\font`y}{\aberrantbox}y
\end{document}
```

[image]

The result *seems* imprecise at high resolution, because the descender of `y` overshoots.

Comment: ...as can be seen [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53221/5764).