# Line numbering fail in Standalone class

Tags: standalone, lineno

In the manual of standalone, it is written, that the margins are removed, so that the page ist croped to the content. In addition, we can use multiple pages thanks to "multi=my", which is what i was looking for. Unfortunately, the line in `\usepackage{lineno}` are not counted, because the margins are removed. But i need both:

1. being able to makge multiple pages which crops the page to the content
2. using the package lineno

> ```
> \documentclass[multi=my,preview,9.5pt]{standalone} 
> \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
> \usepackage[paperwidth=210 mm,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm]{geometry} 
>
> \usepackage{lineno} 
> \usepackage{scrextend} %addmargin
>
> \begin{document}
> \begin{my}
> blabla
>
> text text
> \end{my} 
>  
> \begin{my}
> \begin{linenumbers}
> \modulolinenumbers[1]
>   
> \resetlinenumber
> some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
>   
> \end{linenumbers}
> \end{my} 
>
> \begin{my}
> \begin{addmargin}[20mm]{20mm}
> \begin{linenumbers}
> \modulolinenumbers[1]
>       
> \resetlinenumber
> some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
>       
> \end{linenumbers}
> \end{addmargin}
> \end{my}  
> \end{document}
> ```

Even if i add `\begin{addmargin}[20mm]{20mm}...\end{addmargin}` i dont get the numbers. Is there a workaround?

[image]

Comment: A large border?  Instead of geometry, try using minipages if you want text wrapping with different widths.

Comment: not with different widths, i need variable heights, which are dependent of the content of the page.

Comment: While you **can** specify the height of a minipage, most of the time it is only as high as needed.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244348/make-only-one-page-for-each-chapter/244437?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C31.1388#244437

Comment: @JohnKormylo i tried with minipage, it crops to the content, but still doesnt count the line numbers. As soon as I use standalone, lineno package seems to not work.

Comment: Did you look at the borders (outside the printed area)?  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53220/standalone-producing-cropped-truncated-formulae  Or do minipages normally not produce line numbers?